# What is the purpose of these attachments on my picture frame?

Tags: hanging

Sorry if this is a dumb question. I'm trying to hang a picture and I was wondering what these metal attachments are on the back of the frame. There are two of them.

[image]

Am I supposed to use them for hanging the picture, or are they simply there to stop the frame from tilting in at the top?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are meant to be used to hang the frame. The notches in the hanging bracket are meant to allow a particular position to be selected over a hanger nail in the wall to allow balancing the picture.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose is to hang the frame from a nail or low profile hook. The ridge allows the frame to be shifted slightly to the left or right in the event the frame hangs unevenly. Mounting two hangers on a side spreads the weight between points.